# XML:Mapping and object to table

Tags: ruby, xml, activerecord

My task is to make XML mapping with XML:Mapping in Ruby and save object to a database. Here is the Class:

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
include XML::Mapping
text_node :offer_id , "@id"
array_node :pictures, "picture", :class => Picture
text_node :scu, "vendorCode"
end
```

binding works fine

```
irb(main):003:0> o = Offer.new
=> #<Offer id: nil, offer_id: nil, scu: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

irb(main):004:0> o= Offer.load_from_file("c:\\simple.xml")
=> #<Offer id: nil, offer_id: nil, scu: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Hash is empty and that is not good. But:

```
irb(main):005:0> o.scu
=> "52.61.037"
```

o.save makes blank row in database because of empty hash.
How can I save xml-mapping object to database?